# Search box for hierarchical taxonomies in admin interface

Tags: wp-admin, javascript, admin-ui

When hierarchical taxonomies (like categories) have lots of terms it gets difficult selecting them in the admin interface. A UI solution would be a search-box (like non-hierarchical taxonomies / tags have). Or even better, an added javascript search box to filter the taxonomy tree.

There's a similar older question [Use tag interface for hierarchical taxonomy?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26048/use-tag-interface-for-hierarchical-taxonomy) but the solution applies to manually declaring taxonomies, while I use a plugin (Custom Post types UI) so I don't know how to handle this.

Comment: If the linked solution works, and so it seems, your Q is how to apply a working solution to a 3rd party plugin code. And, sorry, but that sort of Q is off-topic.

Comment: I didn't know that, though, my question is about generally handling large hierarchical taxonomies - say even the default 'categories' - which don't imply any plugin.

I have linked to the previous question to show I did my research - and that solution isn't ideal either, it doesn't allow adding new terms so, just filtering terms/nodes from the taxonomy tree would be a better workaround.