# How to solve performance issue caused by custom post type overview with 20k+ custom taxonomy terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

For a custom post type I added a custom taxonomy which contains 20k+ terms. This is causing some serious performance issues for both the custom post type edit screen (which should be solved removing the default category metabox and adding a custom metabox)

However I am not sure how to solve the slow custom post type overview page. This page seems to also load all custom taxonomy values. So following question concerning this issue:

Is it possible to disable the load of the custom taxonomies on the custom post type overview page? What are the implications of removal of these values here?

Comment: Is your custom post type hierarchical. If it is, set it to false.

Comment: custom post type isn't hierachical, however the custom taxonomy is. When I set the custom taxonomy hierarchical value to false it is a lot faster since it uses the tags interface and autocomplete function.However my taxonomy is hierarchical so that's my issue. Users are not able to add new items when using this method

Comment: Setting your taxonomy's hierarchy to false will just let it act like tags. Unfortunately, I don't have a working solution for this. This is unfortunately a problem with hierarchical taxonomies, it is a bit slower

Comment: By the way we import our custom taxonomy terms once a year with a script. Do you know if there is a difference in the handling of saving/updating taxonomy terms between the hierarchical and non-hierarchical terms? Or is the difference only there in the way the fields are shown to the user a checkbox list(hierarchical) or autocomplete (non-hierarchical) and is the data saved the same way? Is it correct that hierarchical data is only edited/used within the taxonomy edit screen and using the non-hierarchical interface does not interfere with the way the terms are originally stored?

Comment: Solved this problem as described in : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173358/category-page-and-edit-post-page-with-this-category-very-slow